# Complex RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to achieve a specific pattern with a `RecyclerView` list by displaying a dynamic contact list based only on a single `CardView`.

[image: screenshot]

The contact list can have several items in it. Like over 100. Every contact should be a single item and of course, all the area should be scrollable.

A solution would be to make a non-scrollabe `ListView` but the scroll would not be fluid as there are many items in the list.

Another solution would be to create a custom `CardView` item for the top, the middle and the bottom or even overlap all the `CardView` items with a negative margin.

I am wondering if there are some better solutions working with the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Interesting requirement, waiting for an answer for this. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use a nested recycler and intercept (steal) touch events with the child in the area it's in.